# How to refresh a view of a folder in KDE Dolphin?

Tags: dolphin

In Windows' explorer, the address bar has a refresh button:

[image: Windows explorer address bar screenshot, with refresh button highlighted]

This button refreshes the view of the open folder (directory). This is useful, for example, when some file operation has been finished elsewhere, but this particular window of explorer hasn't updated its view yet.

How do I do the same in Dolphin, the default file browser in KDE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple ways this could be done.

1. Press <kbd>F5</kbd>. This is the simplest and fastest way to do it. This is a shortcut for the "Refresh" action.
2. Navigate via the [hamburger menu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_menu) on the right to "For more N actions: > View > Refresh"
   [image: Screenshot of Dolphin showing where the Refresh menu item is located in the hamburger menu]
3. If menubar is enabled, then just click "View > Refresh".

   [image: Screenshot of Dolphin, showing menubar and 'View > Refresh' item selected]
4. Via a "Refresh" button on a toolbar. To configure the button:

   1. Right click the toolbar.
   2. Click "Configure toolbars..."
   3. In the opened dialog, search for "Refresh" in the list of available actions.
   4. Use drag and drop (or the buttons in the middle) to add the "Refresh" action to the list on the right in the position you want.
   5. Click "Apply"

   After that, you can also right click the "Refresh" button to get to the option to hide its text, if you want the button to be icon only.

   [image: Instructions for setting up the refresh button]

Comment: Excellent and comprehensive answer!